# Runtime issues using django and sqlite - too much queries

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, sqlite

I'm having a runtime problem with the following code:

```
# filter start and end date
matches = database.objects.filter(start__gte= Start, end__lte= End)    
# iterate through matches
for Item in matches:
        # filter database again
        test = database.objects.filter(cm1=Item.cm1, cm2=Item.cm2, cm3=Item.cm3)
        # compare first item of filter with iterated Item
        if test[0] == Item:
            TrueRun = True
        else:
            TrueRun = False
```

I have a database with around 80k rows. In a first step I filter the rows I want to look at, should be normally around 8k. In a second step I iterate over all of these items and check if they're unique or the first ones with some specific attributes (`cm1`, `cm2`, `cm3`).

The Problem is now, that I do 8k database queries, which all together take about 15 minutes. Is there any way to accelerate this, for example using a dict before the loop which contains all possibilities of `cm1` and its' matching rows?

Thanks for your help!

**__________________________**

**Edit after Comment**

The default order of my models is different to how it's used here. In program I have about 25 models and check about 12 of them for equalness.

The rest of the loop should not be interesting, because there was another way of checking `TrueRun` before, which took about 2 minutes. Only thing changed is inside #-----# See here:

```
equalnessList = ['cm1','cm2', 'cm3']
for idx, Item in enumerate(matches):
    #-----------------#
    TrueRun = True
    listTrue = []
    for TrueIdx,TrueItem in enumerate(listTrue):
        EqualCount = 0
        for equCrit in equalnessList:
            if getattr(Item,equCrit)!=getattr(matches[TrueItem],equCrit):
                EqualCount += 1
        if EqualCount == len(equalnessList):
            TrueRun = False
            break
    #------------------#
    # Some stuff in here, that can't be changed
    if TrueRun:
        resDict[getattr(Item,'id')] = [True]
        listTrue.append(idx)
    else:
        resDict[getattr(Item,'id')] = [False]
```

Problem here was, that it wasn't working right and didn't use database entries outside of filtered dates for the check.

Comment: What is the default ordering of your model, and can you show the rest of your loop? How are you using `TrueRun`?

Comment: Updated question to your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to tweak this to fit your requirements. In particular, you need to maintain the original sort order within each `cm1, cm2, cm3` group.

```
matches = database.objects.filter(start__gte=Start, end__lte=End)
all_objects = database.objects.all().order_by('cm1', 'cm2', 'cm3', 'sequence')
# replace 'sequence' by field(s) that model is sorted on by default
results_dict = {}
cm1 = None
cm2 = None
cm3 = None
first = False
for obj in all_objects:
    if (obj.cm1 != cm1) or (obj.cm2 != cm2) or (obj.cm3 != cm3):
        cm1 = obj.cm1
        cm2 = obj.cm2
        cm3 = obj.cm3
        first = True
    if obj.start >= Start and obj.end <= End:
        results_dict[obj.id] = first
    first = False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# filter start and end date
matches = database.objects.filter(start__gte=Start, end__lte=End)

# iterate through matches
for item in matches:
    # filter database again and get the id of the first element matched
    first_item = database.objects.filter(cm1=item.cm1, cm2=item.cm2, cm3=item.cm3).values('id').first()
    # compare first item id with the id of filtered "item"
    if first_item['id'] == item.id:
        TrueRun = True
    else:
        TrueRun = False
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way without changing ´matches´? I need it in the original way for some other stuff in the loop..

Comment: Didn't know that, updated my answer! However there might be a much better solution depending on your models structure and what your logic (inside the view) is...

Comment: How can model structure have an impact?

Comment: Because you may (or may not) have declared unecessary relationships between you models. In addition, depending on the logic of your view, the same goal, may (or may not) be achieved with lesser queries (avoiding the `for` loop).

Comment: Models are like: `cm2= models.CharField(db_column='cm2', max_length=30)`

Comment: The view is generating an excel file and calling one time a function, which contains the `for` loop. The data which is processed there will be added to the excel sheet later. `matches` is given to the function and also needed in some other functions, as well as a second time in the loop.

Comment: OK. So did this answer reduced the elapsed time?

Comment: No not really. At least it looks better so I took your code.